# Ruby/Sinatra/DataMapper Many-to-Many how creating an object

Tags: ruby, many-to-many, sinatra, datamapper

I have 2 classes called User and Gig and also a joining table Usergig.

```
  class Usergig
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :gig
  end

  class Gig
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :gigname, String
    property :gigtext, Text

    has n, :usergigs
    has n, :users, :through => :usergigs
  end

  class User
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    property :username, String
    property :realname, String

    has n, :usergigs
    has n, :gigs, :through => :usergigs
  end
```

And when i try to run:

```
  post '/gig/add' do
    user = User.get(1)
    gig = user.gigs.create(:gigname => params[:gig_gigname], :gigtext => params[:gig_gigtext])
  end
```

I get the error:
NoMethodError at /gig/add
undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

I've googled for about two hours now and read the DataMapper documentation.
Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I edited your post to make it readable. You should paste your code (without the line numbers, so we can copy/paste it too!), then select it and press CMD+K (Mac) or ctrl+K (PC).

Comment: Have you tried `:through => Usergig`?

Comment: Ah, thank you! This was my first post and i'm still learning :-) It works fine now, btw. Also seem to forgot to use DataMapper.finalize. Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Usergig try the following:

```
belongs_to :user, :key => true
belongs_to :gig, :key => true
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call DataMapper.finalize...this is what you need to call after all your models are loaded. Rails does this for you, in Sinatra you must call it manually.